# how to access semantic configuration in a controller with symfony2?

Tags: configuration, symfony

I'm following "How to expose a Semantic Configuration for a Bundle" official manual for symfony 2.

I have my configuration.php

```
namespace w9\UserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('w9_user');

        $rootNode
            ->children()
                ->scalarNode('logintext')->defaultValue('Zareejstruj się')->end()
            ->end()
        ;        

        return $treeBuilder;
    }
}
```

And w9UserExtension.php:

```
namespace w9\UserBundle\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\FileLocator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader;

class w9UserExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');
    }
}
```

It may sounds silly, but I'm not able to find the way, how to access logintext parameter in controller?

```
$logintext = $this->container->getParameter("w9_user.logintext");
```

does not work.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In `w9UserExtension.php` after `processConfiguration` line just add

```
$container->setParameter('w9_user.logintext', $config['logintext']);
```

Comment: What if I'm having a bunch of config parameters, how would I set them all at once?

Comment: @acme I wanted to do that too. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to indiscriminately add **all** my config values to the parameters, like @acme, and writing dozens of `setParameter` lines was not lazy enough.

So, I made a `setParameters` method to add to the `Extension` class.

```
/**
 * Set all leaf values of the $config array as parameters in the $container.
 *
 * For example, a config such as this for the alias w9_user :
 *
 * w9_user:
 *   logintext: "hello"
 *   cache:
 *      enabled: true
 *   things:
 *      - first
 *      - second
 *
 * would yield the following :
 *
 * getParameter('w9_user.logintext') == "hello"
 * getParameter('w9_user.cache') ---> InvalidArgumentException
 * getParameter('w9_user.cache.enabled') == true
 * getParameter('w9_user.things') == array('first', 'second')
 *
 * It will resolve `%` variables like it normally would.
 * This is simply a convenience method to add the whole array.
 *
 * @param array $config
 * @param ContainerBuilder $container
 * @param string $namespace The parameter prefix, the alias by default.
 *                          Don't use this, it's for recursion.
 */
protected function setParameters(array $config, ContainerBuilder $container,
                                 $namespace = null)
{
    $namespace = (null === $namespace) ? $this->getAlias() : $namespace;

    // Is the config array associative or empty ?
    if (array_keys($config) !== range(0, count($config) - 1)) {
        foreach ($config as $k => $v) {
            $current = $namespace . '.' . $k;
            if (is_array($v)) {
                // Another array, let's use recursion
                $this->setParameters($v, $container, $current);
            } else {
                // It's a leaf, let's add it.
                $container->setParameter($current, $v);
            }
        }
    } else {
        // It is a sequential array, let's consider it as a leaf.
        $container->setParameter($namespace, $config);
    }
}
```

that you can then use like this :

```
class w9UserExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        // Add them ALL as container parameters
        $this->setParameters($config, $container);

        // ...
    }
}
```

**Warning**

This may be *BAD PRACTICE* if you don't extensively document and/or need such a behavior, as you can expose sensitive configuration information if you forget about it, and lose performance by exposing useless configuration.

Besides, it prevents you from extensively sanitizing the configuration variables before adding them in the container's parameter bag.

If you're using this, you should probably use `parameters:` and not semantic configuration, unless you know what you're doing.

Use at your own risk.